# SQL Server difference between values of many irregular measurements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL server database with a table containing measurement data of 100 measurement point. Each one is measured at a approximately 5 seconds interval. It has the following format:

```
MeasurementPointID           timestamp              value
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:03    100
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:08    120
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:13    130
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:19    160
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:22    200
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:04    400
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:09    405
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:14    420
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:19    445
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:25    470
Etc.
```

I would like to know how to make a view with a change in measurement value since the former timestamp divided by the timeperiod (since former timestamp)

```
MeasurementPointID           timestamp              changeDivPeriod
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:03    0 <-- Zero would be nice here
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:08    4
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:13    2
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:19    5
001234                       03-01-2015 00:02:22    13,333333
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:04    0 <-- Zero would be nice here
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:09    1
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:14    3
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:19    5
001236                       03-01-2015 00:02:25    4,166666
Etc.
```

How would I go about to do that? Is it smart to solve this with a view in the first place?

I am thinking it would be faster/easier to add a trigger to this table and fill a new table (instead of a view) with the calculated values. If so, how do I do that?

Comment: 40/3 is 13.333333 and not 10. Rows (160 and 200) and 3 seconds difference

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the error in the question and added extra tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use windowed function and self join (if needed wrap it with view):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MeasurementPointID ORDER BY [timestamp])
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT c1.MeasurementPointID,
       c1.[timestamp],
       [changeDivPeriod] = 
           CASE WHEN c1.rn = 1 THEN 0 
                ELSE 1.0 * (c1.[value] - c2.[value]) 
                     / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(second, c2.[timestamp], c1.[timestamp]),0)
           END
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.MeasurementPointID = c2.MeasurementPointID 
  AND c1.rn = c2.rn+1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418945)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ MeasurementPointID ║      timestamp      ║ changeDivPeriod ║
╠════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║             001234 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:03 ║ 0               ║
║             001234 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:08 ║ 4               ║
║             001234 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:13 ║ 2               ║
║             001234 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:19 ║ 5               ║
║             001234 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:22 ║ 13.333333333333 ║
║             001236 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:04 ║ 0               ║
║             001236 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:09 ║ 1               ║
║             001236 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:14 ║ 3               ║
║             001236 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:19 ║ 5               ║
║             001236 ║ 2015-03-01 00:02:25 ║ 4.166666666666  ║
╚════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

---

With `SQL Server 2012+` you could utilize **`LEAD/LAG`**:

```
SELECT 
  MeasurementPointID,
  [timestamp],
  [changeDivPeriod] =  COALESCE(1.0 * ([value] - LAG ([value]) OVER ( PARTITION BY MeasurementPointID ORDER BY [timestamp] )) 
                               / NULLIF(DATEDIFF(second, LAG ([timestamp]) OVER ( PARTITION BY MeasurementPointID ORDER BY [timestamp]), [timestamp]),0),0)
FROM #tab
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418948)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm! Since it is sql server 2012, I tried both and the second one is much much faster.